# Canopy and Mac error display

Tags: python, canopy

I installed the Canopy package from Enthought. Everything was fine, but now that I've just taken the new version, it happens that, for some coding errors, I can't visualize any error report, instead it pops up just a big "bug reporter" window, that stops the program and gives me no clue about what I did wrong. I'm sure these are only coding error (like a wrong variable name or similar) because I was able, sometimes, to find them and to make the program run.
Is this a problem someone else encountered? Is there a solution?
Sample code that doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.]
y = [2.,3.,4.,.5,.6,7.,8.,9.,10.]

z = x*y

print z
```

Report given by Canopy:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8B9d2LsyXlccEZfM3BOQTBFVm8&usp=sharing

Tnx a lot!

Comment: Can you post the error text or a screenshot?

Comment: I added some more informations.
p.s. I know that my file has an apparent error, but the point is that I can't get any error report and the program just crashes, giving the "bug reporter" window.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: this is a bug in Canopy 1.3 which is fixed in Canopy 1.4, to be released in the next few days.

Longer answer: the python error traceback, caused by the bug in your code, contains at least one unicode character, and Canopy is breaking on that character.

One source of that unicode character was that your Enthought account name contained the letter `ò`. I have changed that to simple `o`. Please log out of Canopy and log back in. This at least will remove those unicode errors which popped up when Canopy was trying to report unicode errors! :( . However I am not confident that it will remove the first order popups. If not, then the problem is likely to be from one of two sources:

a) unicode characters in your program (though there are not any your sample failing program)

b) unicode characters in some path or filename that you are using (perhaps the %pwd where you are running the program?)

Comment: Thank you so much! You also got a correct guess about my path name.
Thank you very much!
Oh... I read that you are a developer at Enthought. Well, I'll take this chance to thank you also for your work. So much of my thesis work could be done thanks to Enthought products and I'm very happy to be able to use all it's resources for my present and future work.
Have a nice day!